# icheck not working in jquery-steps wizard

Tags: jquery-steps

I am using jquery-steps wizard in one of my projects. 
I have some checkboxes in my form which I am customizing using jquery icheck plugin found here http://icheck.fronteed.com/
But this is not working within jquery steps wizard but as soon as I put those checkboxes outside of wizard then they work perfectly, so definitely issue is using them within wizard.

Can anybody please guide on how to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should try and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, you need to initialize jquery steps first and then other plugin initialization.

```
$("#formulario").steps({});
$('.radio_button').iCheck({
   checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
   radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout this

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/rpw2Lx41/`
```

and make sure you use class "i-check" not "i-checks"